# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading [api.reducerPath]) at Object.extractRehydrationInfo after clearing browser data

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-persist, rtk-query

I have used redux persist with RTK query and redux toolkit. After clearing browser data manually from browser settings,
it could not rehydrate RTK query reducer and showing

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'notesApi')
    at Object.extractRehydrationInfo (notesApi.js:18:1)
    at createApi.ts:234:1
    at memoized (defaultMemoize.js:123:1)
    at createApi.ts:260:1
    at memoized (defaultMemoize.js:123:1)
    at createReducer.ts:239:1
    at Array.filter (<anonymous>)
    at reducer (createReducer.ts:236:1)
    at reducer (createSlice.ts:325:1)
    at combination (redux.js:560:1).
```

Here is the [screenshot of my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jqawj.png).

Official Documentation says

- RTK Query supports rehydration via the extractRehydrationInfo option
  on createApi. This function is passed every dispatched action, and
  where it returns a value other than ***undefined***, that value is used to
  rehydrate the API state for fulfilled & errored queries.

But what about ***undefined*** value like in my case?

This is my store

```
const reducers = combineReducers({
  userReducer,
  [notesApi.reducerPath]: notesApi.reducer,
});

const persistConfig = {
  key: "root",
  storage,
};

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(
  persistConfig,
  reducers
);

const store = configureStore({
  reducer: persistedReducer,
  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
    getDefaultMiddleware({
      serializableCheck: {
        ignoredActions: [FLUSH, REHYDRATE, PAUSE, PERSIST, PURGE, REGISTER],
      },
    }).concat(notesApi?.middleware),
});    

export default store;
```

This is the notesApi

```
export const notesApi = createApi({
 reducerPath: "notesApi" ,
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({
    baseUrl: "http://localhost:5000/api/notes/",
    prepareHeaders: (headers, { getState }) => {
      const token = getState().userReducer.userInfo.token;
      console.log(token);
      if (token) {
        headers.set("authorization", `Bearer ${token}`);
      }
      return headers;
    },
  }),
  extractRehydrationInfo(action, { reducerPath }) {
    if (action.type === REHYDRATE) {
        return action.payload[reducerPath]
    }
  },
  tagTypes: ["notes"],

  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    createNote: builder.mutation({
      query: (data) => ({
        url: `/create`,
        method: "POST",
        body: data,
      }),
      invalidatesTags: ["notes"],
    }),
    getSingleNote: builder.query({
      query: (id) => ({
        url: `/${id}`,
      }),
      providesTags: ["notes"],
    })
});
export const {  useGetSingleNoteQuery,
  useCreateNoteMutation,
} = notesApi;
```

Comment: I'm indagating the same problem at the moment

Answer (score 2):

I've run into this issue a few times and it seems to manifest when attempting to rehydrate the store when there isn't anything in localStorage to hydrate from.

The error is saying it can't read `"notesApi"` of undefined when running `extractRehydrationInfo`. `"notesApi"` is the API slice's `reducerPath` value. The action's payload is undefined.

```
extractRehydrationInfo(action, { reducerPath }) {
  if (action.type === REHYDRATE) {
    return action.payload[reducerPath]; // <-- action.payload undefined
  }
},
```

To resolve this issue I've simply used the Optional Chaining operator on the action payload.

Example:

```
extractRehydrationInfo(action, { reducerPath }) {
  if (action.type === REHYDRATE) {
    return action.payload?.[reducerPath];
  }
},
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and I just preceded the constant with the keyword "export"

```js
import { createApi, fetchBaseQuery } from '@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react';

const BASE_URL = 'http://192.168.34.62:8000/api/';

export const api = createApi({
  reducerPath: 'api',
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({ baseUrl: BASE_URL }),
  endpoints: (build) => ({
    getUserProfile: build.query({
      query: (id) => `profiles/${id}/`,
      method: 'Get',
    }),
    updateUserProfile: build.mutation({
      query: ({ id, newData }) => ({
        url: `profiles/${id}/`,
        method: 'PUT',
        body: newData,
      }),
    }),
  }),
});

export const { useGetUserProfileQuery, useUpdateUserProfileMutation } = api;
```